# grpc c++ async completion queue events

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, grpc

I am trying to understand the grpc c++ async model flow. This article ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318889/asynchronous-model-in-grpc-c) ) already explains many of my doubts.
Here is the code for  [grpc_asycn_server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc). To understand when CompletionQueue is getting requests, I added a few print statements as follows:

First inside the HandleRpcs() function.

```
void HandleRpcs() {
    // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients.
    new CallData(&service_, cq_.get());
    void* tag;  // uniquely identifies a request.
    bool ok;
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
      std::cout << i << std::endl; ///////////////////////////////
      // Block waiting to read the next event from the completion queue. The
      // event is uniquely identified by its tag, which in this case is the
      // memory address of a CallData instance.
      // The return value of Next should always be checked. This return value
      // tells us whether there is any kind of event or cq_ is shutting down.
      GPR_ASSERT(cq_->Next(&tag, &ok));
      GPR_ASSERT(ok);
      static_cast<CallData*>(tag)->Proceed();
      i++;
    }
  }
```

and inside the proceed() function:

```
void Proceed() {
  if (status_ == CREATE) {
    // Make this instance progress to the PROCESS state.
    status_ = PROCESS;

    // As part of the initial CREATE state, we *request* that the system
    // start processing SayHello requests. In this request, "this" acts are
    // the tag uniquely identifying the request (so that different CallData
    // instances can serve different requests concurrently), in this case
    // the memory address of this CallData instance.
    std::cout<<"RequestSayHello called"<<std::endl; ////////////////////////////
    service_->RequestSayHello(&ctx_, &request_, &responder_, cq_, cq_,
                              this);
  } else if (status_ == PROCESS) {
    // Spawn a new CallData instance to serve new clients while we process
    // the one for this CallData. The instance will deallocate itself as
    // part of its FINISH state.
    new CallData(service_, cq_);

    // The actual processing.
    std::string prefix("Hello ");
    reply_.set_message(prefix + request_.name());

    // And we are done! Let the gRPC runtime know we've finished, using the
    // memory address of this instance as the uniquely identifying tag for
    // the event.
    status_ = FINISH;
    responder_.Finish(reply_, Status::OK, this);
  } else {
    std::cout<<"deallocated"<<std::endl; ////////////////////////////
    GPR_ASSERT(status_ == FINISH);
    // Once in the FINISH state, deallocate ourselves (CallData).
    delete this;
  }
}
```

Once I run the server and the one client ( [client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_client.cc)) then the server prints the following:

```
RequestSayHello called
i = 0
RequestSayHello called
i = 1
deallocated
i = 2
```

The second `RequestSayHello called` makes sense because of the creation of new `CallData` instance. 
**My question** is how come `proceed()`function executed the second time and `deallocated` gets printed?

Comment: Are you sure you have your output ordering correct? I ran the example with your added print statements in the same locations and got the following output:

`
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:50051
RequestSayHello called
i = 0
RequestSayHello called
i = 1
deallocated
i = 2
`

Comment: Sorry, I=0 should be in second position

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The completion queue (`cq_`) structure handles several types of events, including both request *and* response events. The first call to `proceed()` enters the `PROCESS` stage of the state machine for the `CallData` object.

During this stage:
1. A new `CallData` object is created; this inserts a request event into `cq_` as you mentioned
2. The `responder_` is called with the reply object; this inserts a response event into `cq_`

Upon receiving the response event from `cq_`, `proceed()` is called again on the first `CallData` object, which is now in the `FINISH` state, so clean up is performed and `deallocated` is printed.

Comment: `The responder_ is called with the reply object` this happens inside `Finish` call right ?

Comment: Correct, the `service_->RequestSayHello` call sets up a binding between the `cq_` and `responder_`. When `responser_.Finish` is called, the reply is sent back to the client and an event arrives on `cq_` indicating that the response was sent.

Comment: Hi @Matthew Rasa, does all completion queue attach to the same stub? How do the completion queue data send by stub?